# How to access updated document in mongoose in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongoose and typescript and I remember when I wanted to access the updated document in updateOne pre-middleware, I use this code

```
Schema.pre('updateOne', function (next) {
    const data = this.getUpdate()

    
    next()
})
```

but I can't use **getUpdate()** method in typescript so, What is the alternative to get access to the updated document?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and this is how I resolve it.

1. stringify the `getUpdate()` method
2. then `parse` it to a Javascript object

example:

```
const _update = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getUpdate()));
  if (_update.quantity !== undefined) {
    this.set({ inStock: _update.quantity > 0 });
  }
```